# Raphael.js customAttributes animation

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I'm trying to create a simple animation of a circle sector using Raphael.js. The animation should unfold circle sector from 0 to 2 * Pi. The problem is that it just draw a circle without any animation after 1 second.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="raphael.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var paper = Raphael("holder");

            paper.ca.sector = function (x, y, r1, r2, startAngle, endAngle, color) {
                    var x11 = x + r1 * Math.sin(startAngle);
                    var y11 = y - r1 * Math.cos(startAngle);
                    var x21 = x + r1 * Math.sin(endAngle);
                    var y21 = y - r1 * Math.cos(endAngle);

                    var x12 = x + r2 * Math.sin(startAngle);
                    var y12 = y - r2 * Math.cos(startAngle);
                    var x22 = x + r2 * Math.sin(endAngle);
                    var y22 = y - r2 * Math.cos(endAngle);

                    var big = 0;
                    if (endAngle - startAngle > Math.PI) 
                        big = 1;

                    var pathList = ["M", x12, y12,
                                    "A", r2, r2, 0, big, 1, x22, y22,
                                    "L", x21, y21, 
                                    "A", r1, r1, 0, big, 0, x11, y11,
                                    "Z"];

                    return {path: pathList, fill: color, stroke: "none"};
                }

            var p = paper.path().attr({sector: [300, 300, 100, 140, 0, 0.0001, "pink"]});
            p.animate({sector: [300, 300, 100, 140, 0, Math.PI * 1.999999, "pink"]}, 1000, "bounce");
        };
    </script>

    <div id="holder" style="width: 700px; height: 700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the long listing.

So the question why does it happen? And what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
        var paper = Raphael("holder");

        var createSector = function (x, y, r1, r2, startAngle, endAngle, color) {
                var x11 = x + r1 * Math.sin(startAngle);
                var y11 = y - r1 * Math.cos(startAngle);
                var x21 = x + r1 * Math.sin(endAngle);
                var y21 = y - r1 * Math.cos(endAngle);

                var x12 = x + r2 * Math.sin(startAngle);
                var y12 = y - r2 * Math.cos(startAngle);
                var x22 = x + r2 * Math.sin(endAngle);
                var y22 = y - r2 * Math.cos(endAngle);

                var big = 0;
                if (endAngle - startAngle > Math.PI) 
                    big = 1;

                var pathList = ["M", x12, y12,
                                "A", r2, r2, 0, big, 1, x22, y22,
                                "L", x21, y21, 
                                "A", r1, r1, 0, big, 0, x11, y11,
                                "Z"];

                return {path: pathList, fill: color, stroke: "none"};
            }

        var p = paper.path();
           p.attr(createSector(300, 300, 100, 140, 0, 0.001, "pink"));
        p.animate(createSector(300, 300, 100, 140, 0.01, Math.PI * 1.999999, "pink"), 1000, "bounce");
```

Still I am not sure yet, why your code is not working

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjsKd/)

EDIT:
Ok, I ve been trying some values and it looks like some kind of a bug in raphael, since the fill of the path is not used in conjunction with the animate.

```
var paper = Raphael("holder");

        paper.customAttributes.sector = function (x, y, r1, r2, startAngle, endAngle, color,strokeWidth) {
                var x11 = x + r1 * Math.sin(startAngle);
                var y11 = y - r1 * Math.cos(startAngle);
                var x21 = x + r1 * Math.sin(endAngle);
                var y21 = y - r1 * Math.cos(endAngle);

                var x12 = x + r2 * Math.sin(startAngle);
                var y12 = y - r2 * Math.cos(startAngle);
                var x22 = x + r2 * Math.sin(endAngle);
                var y22 = y - r2 * Math.cos(endAngle);

                var big = 0;
                if (endAngle - startAngle > Math.PI) 
                    big = 1;

                var pathList = ["M", x12, y12,
                                "A", r2, r2, 0, big, 1, x22, y22,
                                "L", x21, y21, 
                                "A", r1, r1, 0, big, 0, x11, y11,
                                "Z"];

            return {path: pathList, fill: color,'stroke-width':strokeWidth};
            }

        var p = paper.path();
           p.attr({sector: [300, 300, 100, 140, 0, 0.0001, "#caac12",1]});
        p.animate({sector: [300, 300, 100, 140, 0.0001, Math.PI * 1.999999, "#cacaca",0]}, 3000);
```

[JSFiddle demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LjsKd/2/)